# Renderscript - processing 2 images

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision, renderscript

Quickly going through the documentation I haven't found any obvious way of passing 2 images as inputs - has anyone done this or know if its possible with the current implementation?

Cheers, 
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel inputs are currently limited to a single allocation.  You can pass additional allocations at the global scope and then use rsGetElementAt(thealloc, coords...) to get the data out of them.

Comment: Thanks Jason, do you know if there is a performance cost of using rsGetElementAt(thealloc, coords...)? At the moment I'm using NDK/OpenCV - runs fine on a Samsung Note but the Sony Z takes almost twice the time (which is why I'm looking at alternatives).